# Two one-to-many relationships between the same two models

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have a `Player` class and each player owns X amount of `Character` instances:

```
class Player(Model):
    characters = relationship('Character', back_populates='owner')

class Character(Model):
    owner = relationship('Player', back_populates='characters')
    owner_id = Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
```

But now I want to split these characters into two separate lists, ones which are in the `graveyard` and the normal `characters` list:

```
class Player(Model):
    characters = relationship('Character', back_populates='owner')
    graveyard = relationship('Character', back_populates='owner')

class Character(Model):
    owner = relationship('Player', back_populates='characters')
    owner_id = Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
```

But as you can see, there's no way for SQLAlchemy to differentiate between the two lists. How can I enable such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a bold assumption there is a way to distinguish whether a character is in graveyard or not. Otherwise this would make no sense.  If "Character" table contains information about the location of the character, then what you need is "alternate join" as described here:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#specifying-alternate-join-conditions

Here is a silly but working example (ignore the gobbledygook with sessions  etc, I just copypasted a new model on piece of old code) if I understood your problem right. It will create a model, insert a player, one alive and one dead character and then display them. Is this what you are looking for?

```
from sqlalchemy import Integer, ForeignKey, String, Column, Boolean, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine("postgresql://test:test@localhost/test", echo=False)
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)


class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    characters = relationship('Character', primaryjoin="and_(Character.player_id == Player.id, \
                              Character.alive == True)")
    graveyard = relationship('Character', primaryjoin="and_(Character.player_id == Player.id, \
                              Character.alive == False)")


class Character(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'character'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    alive = Column(Boolean)
    player_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

try:
    p = Player(name="foo")
    Session.add(p)
    Session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    Session.rollback()

try:
    p = Session.query(Player).filter(Player.name == "foo").one()
    c1 = Character(name="c1", alive=True, player_id=p.id)
    c2 = Character(name="c2", alive=False, player_id=p.id)
    Session.add(c1)
    Session.add(c2)
    Session.commit()
except IntegrityError:
    Session.rollback()

player = Session.query(Player).filter(Player.name == "foo").one()

print player
for c in player.characters:
    print c.name

for c in player.graveyard:
    print c.name
```

Comment: "I make a bold assumption there is a way to distinguish whether a character is in graveyard or not." not really, none other than which list he's in... :s I guess I should just add a `bool` flag which doesn't really do anything other than tells which list it's in, right? But yeah other than that this seems good enough

Comment: But if there is no flag whatsoever, then there is no way for the database to distinguish between graveyard and character. One very important thing to keep in mind is that SQLAlchemy does not transfer relationship rules to database. Your database looks exactly the same with or without relationship clauses. They are just sqlalchemy helpers to provide access to classes in your code and to simplify queries. The only line affecting database is the player_id = .. .ForeignKey constraint. It changes database.

Comment: You do not need any relationship statements if you do not like them. You can always do the same thing in an individual query. They are there just to help you to organise your code and make it more readable. Database does  not care about them.  So yes, you need a flag in your character table, and you can query it either this way or just the "standard" way using Session.query method.

Comment: Yeah this all makes sense now! Your solution isn't the *exact* solution I'll use but it helped me better understand how SQLAlchemy works. I ended up creating two separate classes (the graveyard example was simpliefied) and tables, thanks and kiitos :)